# what type of timer does this site use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-css

me and my team really working on a site like [www.bidrivals.com/us](http://www.bidrivals.com/us) (penny auction site)

i browse it codes
found

```
<div class="timer online">
<div class="text">00:00:03</div>
</div>
```

i could not found anything on the js  file of this site ... 
can any body tell me which type of js timer that this site is using?
any example code for that?
anything available like this in j query or prototype framework ?

Comment: Why does it matter what *that* site is doing? Just look up how to do a timer in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript provides the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions to run actions at a "set time" in milliseconds.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Example:

```
// this is will act like a counter on the page
var t = 0,
    div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = t;
document.body.appendChild(div);
setInterval(function () {
    t += 1;
    div.innerHTML = t;
}, 1000); // this will run once every second
```

In the case of this website, they run an XHR request every second to get the data for each bid.  Checkout the console to see the requests.

Comment: XHR request ON every second !!!??? ....  how they optimize that ? it cause heavy server load !

Comment: @SinaMiandashti 1 req/second is really not that much. Most servers well get much more traffic than that.

Comment: if u want to develop such site which php framework and DB ORM and other stuff u preferred ? any suggestion plz

Comment: A `GET` request is lower overhead than `POST` as well. Any framework you prefer would be fine. Kohana and Codeignitor are popular frameworks.

Comment: zend framework 2.0 or 1.0 is slow for this ? how about using doctirne ? make it slower or faster ? plz give me a complete combination ... what type of cache should i use ?

Comment: I don't know anything about zend. A site like this doesn't seem to have a lot of overhead in general. Google around for other questions. Anymore discussion is beyond the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

there is a server side count, to control the hits and time.

check [$.post in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), in this case you call an server side script who inform  webpage the times, and the bid actions... once with this data, you change de div values with callback function.

check the network requests using firebug, you will see a json coming from a getData webpage.

Comment: u mean something like this ? http://www.bidrivals.com/data/getData.php?sid=22&x=1322937796431 ....  exactly !! but how optimize they ARE !!!  can u guess what is sid and what is x (as get vars) ?

Comment: x is something like a time variable, to avoid cache. And sid, maybe a info saying how much information they need (last 22 bids in this case?)

Comment: if u want to develop such site which php framework and DB ORM and other stuff u preferred ? any suggestion plz

Comment: and tel me how to create that random time number in js to avoid cache ? and jQuery.Get or Post is fast enough for that request? what is bidrivals using for that GET ?

Comment: create the random time is easy with (new Date()).getTime() on javascript. If you are worried about server load, consider use of [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).